# Weird Powershell performance issue

Tags: c#, performance, powershell

**NOTE:** This is a solution for Project Euler [Problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14). If you still want to solve it yourself then don't read on.

The problem was to find the number below one million which, as starting number for the [Collatz sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_sequence), produces the longest such sequence. My initial code was as follows:

```
$r = @{}

for($i = 1; $i -lt 1000000; $i++) {
    $n = 0
    $a = $i
    while ($a -gt 1) {
        if ($r[$a]) {
            $n += $r[$a]
            break
        }
        if ($a % 2 -eq 0) {
            $a /= 2
        } else {
            $a = $a * 3 + 1
        }
        $n++
    }
    $r[$i] = $n
}

$r.GetEnumerator() | sort Value | select -l 1 | %{$_.Key}
```

which tries to use a hashtable as cache for sub-sequences already encountered to save time. I was quite surprised when that script had a runtime of over eight minutes on my machine. Re-creating the same code in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Problem14
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ht = new Dictionary<long, int>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            long j = i;

            while (j > 1)
            {
                if (ht.ContainsKey(j))
                {
                    count += ht[j];
                    break;
                }
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                    j /= 2;
                else
                    j = 3 * j + 1;

                count++;
            }
            ht[i] = count;
        }

        KeyValuePair<long, int> max = new KeyValuePair<long, int>();
        foreach (var n in ht)
        {
            if (n.Value > max.Value)
                max = n;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(max.Key);
    }
}
```

had a runtime of just over one second. I knew that speed of execution wasn't a prime goal in Powershell. It's an adminstration language and for those tasks the ratio of PS code to cmdlets is likely very different from what I do here.

Still, I don't know what exactly causes the slowdown.

Suspecting the hash table, I replaced it for caching with an array. This resulted in an execution time around 200 ms in C# and about 32 minutes in Powershell. Code was as follows:

```
$r = ,0*1000000

for($i = 1; $i -lt 1000000; $i++) {
    $n = 0
    $a = $i
    while ($a -gt 1) {
        if ($r[$a]) {
            $n += $r[$a]
            break
        }
        if ($a % 2 -eq 0) {
            $a /= 2
        } else {
            $a = $a * 3 + 1
        }
        $n++
    }
    if ($i -lt 1000000) {
        $r[$i] = $n
    }
}

$max = 0
for($i=1; $i -lt 1000000; $i++) {
    if ($r[$i] > $r[$max]) {
        $max = $i
    }
}
$max
```

and

```
using System;

class Problem14
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var cache = new int[1000000];

        for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            long j = i;

            while (j > 1)
            {
                if (j < 1000000 && cache[j] != 0)
                {
                    count += cache[j];
                    break;
                }
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                    j /= 2;
                else
                    j = 3 * j + 1;

                count++;
            }
            cache[i] = count;
        }

        var max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < cache.Length; i++)
        {
            if (cache[i] > cache[max])
                max = i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(max);
    }
}
```

A completely cacheless variant was around 1.2 seconds in C#. Didn't try yet in Powershell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, PowerShell is an interpreted language (not jitted, nor compiled). That's always going to hurt. ;-)

Secondly, there are some language constructs that you may use that can avoid multiple interpreted steps. For example, instead of using a for(;;) statement, use a range:

```
0..1000000 | foreach-object { foo $_
```

Might help a bit.

Most importantly, avoid the excessive use of break and continue keywords in loops - invert your logic if possible to avoid this. Internally, these keywords signal using .NET exceptions, and are therefore expensive operations.

Hope this helps your understanding somewhat.

EDIT: these keywords use .NET exceptions for signalling

From System.Management.Automation.FlowControlNode.Execute(...):

```
switch (this._tokenId)
    {
        case TokenId.ExitToken:
        {
            int exitCode = this.GetExitCode(result);
            throw new ExitException(base.NodeToken, exitCode);
        }
        case TokenId.ReturnToken:
            throw new ReturnException(base.NodeToken, result);

        case TokenId.BreakToken:
            label = this.GetLabel(result, context);
            throw new BreakException(base.NodeToken, label);

        case TokenId.ContinueToken:
            label = this.GetLabel(result, context);
            throw new ContinueException(base.NodeToken, label);
```

-Oisin

Comment: At least in my benchmarks the pipeline solution using ranges always was a little slower than an iterative one. A for loop doesn't involve creating a range and passing objects through the pipeline, for example :-)

Comment: Yea, the Pipeline will be slower.  Anything that loops will be slower in PowerShell than C#.

Comment: Oh, and may I ask for the source of the fact that break and continue are exceptions internally? Considering the other fairly normal structured programming keywords and how they seem to work this sounds a little awkward to me to solve that with exceptions.

Comment: Edited original post to show code (from Reflector). Oh, and sorry about the pipeline/range hint. I got that backwards. You're right, the pipeline tends to be slower [in most cases].